# C#, VisualStudio, How to get ID of Errors and Warnings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio, how can I get the errorcode or warningcode from the "Error List" Window?

Also how can I configure that specific warnings are errors?

Comment: You mean programmatically to get warnings text and their ID's?

Comment: @clamp you can configure that specific warnings are errors using VS or just a notepad, see my explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure warnings:

- Open the project's Properties dialog box.
- Click the Build property page.

Now you can

1) Modify the `Warning Level` property.

2) Set `treat warnings as errors` to `All` or `Specific warnings`

[image: Screenshot]

**Also**,
It is possible to set specific warnings as errors by editing the project file directly using a text editor such as notepad, sublime text, etc. C# project files can be found in the project's folder and have the extension, "csproj". Locate `PropertyGroup` element and add nested element

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <WarningsAsErrors>612</WarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```

BTW, you can set `Treat all warnings as errors` in Visual Studio, and then add

```
<WarningsNotAsErrors>618,1030,1701,1702</WarningsNotAsErrors>
```

to `PropertyGroup`
to **EXCLUDE** only some **specific** ones

Answer (score 4):

You can't find them in Error List, but if you check the Output window it will have the detail like:

> warning CS0219: The variable 'j' is assigned but its value is never
>   used

[image]

Comment: You can also copy the errors/warnings using plain old Ctrl+C, which makes it easier to search for it online.

Comment: @ErikSchierboom, yes, but it will not show the warning number, it will only be the infomration conatined in the error list.

Comment: isn't 0219 the error code of that warning? in the format of CSXXXX you can then do #pragma warning disable 0219